# single-spa axios calls redirecting to single-spa port

Tags: json, axios, single-spa

I am trying out single-spa and is stuck with the below issue

I have single spa running on port 5000 and 2 apps running on port 8081 and 8082.
The apps were already running applications converted to single-spa. The apps have axios calls to get data from the server.
After the migration, the Axios calls uses the URL http://localhost:5000/json/xxx.json where it should have been http://localhost:8081/json/xxx.json

How can I get this issue fixed? How can I make sure that each application calls its own backend and not single spa?

sample axios call

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   axios.get('/json/xx.json', {
   responseType: 'json'
   })
   .then((response) => {
   resolve(response.data)
   })
   .catch(reject)
   .finally(() => {
     doSomething()
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use env variables for your axios url instead of setting them with relative path.

```js
function getAxiosInstanceFor(baseURL: string):{
return axios.create({
  baseURL,
  timeout: 20000,
})

}
// App1.js
// Do same thing to get api/App2.js resource.

const APP1_BASE_URL = process.env.APP1_BASE_URL;

axiosInsance = getAxiosInstanceFor(APP1_BASE_URL );

function get(path: string){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   axiosInsance.get(`${path}`, {
   responseType: 'json'
   })
   .then((response) => {
   resolve(response.data)
   })
}
   .catch(reject)
   .finally(() => {
     doSomething()
   })
})

export const { get };

// somewhereElse.js
// call functions like so
import App1 from 'App1.js';
import App2 from 'App2.js';

App1.get("/json/xx.json")
App2.get("/json/xx.json")
```